# How many topics can a whisper message have?

Tags: dapps, whisper, message, shh

I'm thinking in a new DAPP that may use whisper extensively. To evaluate the viability of the DAPP, I need to know if there is a limit on the number of topics that a whisper message can have. I would like also to know how many topics a single filter can listen to, and how many whisper filters can coexist in the same node.

Answer (score 7):

At this point it's difficult to give a very accurate answer to your questions as Whisper is still very much in its infancy stage, however I'll attempt to answer your question with the *implemenation* that's currently in operation.

The amount of whisper topics that you may use for your messages and filters are [theoretical infinite](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/develop/whisper/filter.go#L31). Please note that whisper topics are [hashed](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/develop/whisper/topic.go#L34) and only the first 4 bytes are used.

The amount of filters you can use is not specced, it depends fully on the implementation.